# Android: reading zipfile - EOFException

Tags: android

I have downloaded a zip file from internet and saved in internal storage. When I try to read the zip file, I keep getting the EOFException. Also, I notice that the length obtained from file.length() in the snippet below is larger than the actual file.

here's my code snippet.

```
File file = new File(filePath + "/" + zipFile);
    long len = file.length();


    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(bis);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method,

```
public static void unzipFile(ZipFile zipFile, File destinationPath) {
      Enumeration files = zipFile.entries();
      File f = null;
      FileOutputStream fos = null;

      while (files.hasMoreElements()) {
         try {
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) files.nextElement();
            InputStream eis = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            f = new File(destinationPath.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + entry.getName());

            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
               f.mkdirs();
               continue;
            }
            else {
               f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
               f.createNewFile();
            }

            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

            while ((bytesRead = eis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
               fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(0, DEBUG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            continue;
         }
         finally {
            if (fos != null) {
               try {
                  fos.close();
               }
               catch (IOException e) {
                  Log.e(0, DEBUG_TAG, e.getMessage());
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: I have tried this but when I do

`File file = new File(filePath + "/" + zipFileName);`
`ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);`

it gives error - ArrayIndexOoutOfBounds

Comment: File file = new File(filePath + "/" + "zipFileName.zip");

unzipFile(new ZipFile(file),new File(destinationPath));